# What's the purpose of kqueue EV_ENABLE and EV_DISABLE

Tags: c, macos, kqueue

I'm trying to understand the use case for EV_DISABLE and EV_ENABLE in kqueue.

```
int KQueue = kqueue();

struct kevent ev = {
  .ident = fd,
  .filter = EVFILT_READ,
  .flags = EV_ADD | EV_DISABLE,
  .udata = somePtr
};

kevent(KQueue, &ev, 1, NULL, 0, NULL);

...

struct kevent ev = {
  .ident = fd,
  .filter = EVFILT_READ,
  .flags = EV_ENABLE
};

kevent(KQueue, &ev, 1, &ev, 1, NULL);
```

Now, when the last call to `kevent()` returns, `ev.udata` is `NULL` instead of `somePtr`. If `kevent()` updates the `udata` pointer even though EV_ADD isn't set, instead of just enable the event, what is the reason for allowing you to add a disabled event, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `kqueue` did not update `udata`. YOU updated `udata` by leaving it uninitialized. You are registering the filter with new values. The point of `udata` is to cross the kernel with it. You can keep your own pointer in `userland`.
2. The point of disabling an event is that you want it returned at another call, or that you don't want to cause `kqueue` to return when it is triggered, but at a different time.

Answer (score 4):

Another use case for `EV_ENABLE` is in conjunction with `EV_DISPATCH`. This is necessary in multi-threaded scenario where you have multiple threads waiting for events in a `kevent()` call. When an event occurs, without `EV_DISPATCH`, all your threads would be woken up on the same event causing a thundering herd problem. With `EV_DISPATCH`, the event is delivered to *one* thread and disabled right after that (ie. atomically from userspace point of view). The thread then handles the event and may re-enable it.